# Rails 5, best way to save an image to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I just started learning rails, and am making my own CRUD app on my own just to get familiar with it.

Ideally the app will have some sort of "Post" that will have a form and an image that will be submitted along with it acting as the "Main Profile" image.

This main profile image will be displayed in a "grid" view on the index page. I've heard of paperclip for Rails....but is that still the best option in holding an image in the database? or is it better to host the image somewhere else? Im somewhat new to a lot of web-dev concepts.

Thanks!

(Database will be postgres on prod at least and sqlite during dev)

Comment: Hey, you can use [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for the host images. If you used lastest version of rails you can go for active_storage [link](https://rubyinrails.com/2017/07/21/rails-introduces-active-storage-for-file-uploads/)

Comment: I would also recommend looking into some gems to help with this, I use the paperclip gem myself, but there are a few good ones out there, https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip  .

Comment: I don't think Paperclip stores files in the database does it? In my app it just stores on the file system and a link to the file in the database. Would the OP be willing to re-think his requirement to store files in the database?

Comment: @VivekSingh I think carrierwave is what my company uses, this is for a personal project but it'll be good to use something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing images in a DB isn't a good idea - it is generally slow and will affect the DB performance.

I would recommend the [Shrine file attachment framework](http://shrinerb.com), which is the most lightweight and, at the same time, most sophisticated of its kind.

You could read a [very interesting article](https://twin.github.io/better-file-uploads-with-shrine-motivation/) by Shrine's author with the comparison of different file attachment frameworks.